# Testcontainers custom internal network with exposed port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-boot-test, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I want to write integration test in java for spring boot app using hazelcast and mongo database:

spring app is using hazelcast - hazelcast has to expose port to spring app, spring app has to know it

hazelcast is using mongo database, hazelcast has to know mongo port, mongo container must be visible to hazelcast.

There are two containers - hazelcast and mongo. Possibly they could be in [internal network](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#advanced-networking), but is it possible to expose a hazelcast port to spring then?

How can I get it done best way?